# Class Does Not Exist Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2.2

After installing the extension from magenerds, I wasn't able to run the compiler, I was getting an error mentioned below.

I've tried removing the extension but no luck.

Tried the following Steps

- Removing from /app/code
- Disabling by entering 0 in config.php
- Empty out /var/generated/* folder

Still, I am getting

```
Class Magenerds\PageDesigner\Model\ValidationState does not exist
```

Comment: Have you done a search throughout the project to see if any other classes or configuration is using that class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue here's what I did

I went in my var/cache folder and remove all the folders by doing rm -rf *

After I ran the compiler and everything is fixed compiler was running, It appears that class got stuck in the memory.